# mySQL getting max id where

Tags: mysql

I have rows like

```
 id     uid     oid     cname 
 20     18       0      hey
 21     18       1      ball
```

And I'm trying to get the number of the highest `oid` so that I can +1 to it into a variable

Using the below I get a return of `Resource id #6`

`SELECT MAX( oid ) AS O, uid
FROM c_feed
WHERE uid = '18'`

Comment: The error is in your PHP part, which you didn't even mentioned in your question or in your tags. Just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Last_Insert_ID() as in here [get max id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511826/how-bad-is-using-select-maxid-in-mysql-instead-of-mysql-insert-id-in-php) if you are after the last inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

You're (probably) receiving an array as output, not a single number. You'll likely need to write something like this:

```
$db_row = mysql_fetch_array($db_results);
$my_var = $db_row['O'];
```